# Restructure / reshape data frame ( r )

Tags: r, reshape2

My dataset has repeated observations for people that work on projects. I need a data frame with two columns that list 'combinations' of projects for each person and time point. Let me explain with an example:

This is my data:

```
ID    Week    Project    
01    1       101
01    1       102 
01    1       103
01    2       101
01    2       102
02    1       101
02    1       102
02    2       101
```

Person 1 (ID = 1) worked on three projects in week 1. This means that there are six possible combinations of projects (project_i & project_j) for this person, in this week.

This is what I need

```
ID   Week    Project_i  Project_j
01    1      101        101
01    1      101        102
01    1      101        103
01    1      102        101
01    1      102        102    
01    1      102        103
01    1      103        101
01    1      103        102
01    1      103        103
01    2      101        101
01    2      101        102
01    2      102        101
01    2      102        102
02    1      101        101
02    1      101        102
02    1      102        101
02    1      102        102
02    2      101        101
```

Losing cases that only have one project per week is not an issue.

I have tried basic r and reshape2 for a bit, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Right now, I have not included the same project ID in the same row (i.e., 
101  101)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[, CJ(P1 = Project, P2 = Project)[P1 != P2], by=.(ID, Week)]

    ID Week  P1  P2
 1:  1    1 101 102
 2:  1    1 101 103
 3:  1    1 102 101
 4:  1    1 102 103
 5:  1    1 103 101
 6:  1    1 103 102
 7:  1    2 101 102
 8:  1    2 102 101
 9:  2    1 101 102
10:  2    1 102 101
```

`CJ` is the Cartesian Join of two vectors, taking all combinations.

If you don't want both (101,102) and (102,101), use `P1 > P2` instead of `P1 != P2`. Oh, the OP has changed the question... so use `P1 <= P2`.

Comment: This seems to work, but r is still running. Do you think that this will take long (or is feasible at all) for 2 million observations?

Comment: @HJ_r It's probably not. You need to consider the combinatorial problem you're attempting to tackle. You can type `combos = DT[, .(n = .N*(.N-1L)), by = .(ID, Week)]` to see the size of the problem. `combos[, sum(n)]` will show the total number of rows in the result, and you can also look at `combos[, summary(n)]`, `combos[, hist(n)]`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The key step is `tidyr::complete()` combined with `dplyr::group_by()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>% 
  rename(Project_i = Project) %>%
  mutate(Project_j = Project_i) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Week) %>%
  complete(Project_i, Project_j) %>%
  filter(Project_i != Project_j)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a base option using `expand.grid`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, paste(df$ID, df$Week)), function(x){
    x2 <- expand.grid(ID = unique(x$ID), 
                      Week = unique(x$Week), 
                      Project_i = unique(x$Project), 
                      Project_j = unique(x$Project))
    # omit if 101 102 is different from 102 101; make `<` if 101 101 not possible
    x2[x2$Project_i <= x2$Project_j,]
}))

#       ID Week Project_i Project_j
# 1 1.1  1    1       101       101
# 1 1.4  1    1       101       102
# 1 1.5  1    1       102       102
# 1 1.7  1    1       101       103
# 1 1.8  1    1       102       103
# 1 1.9  1    1       103       103
# 1 2.1  1    2       101       101
# 1 2.3  1    2       101       102
# 1 2.4  1    2       102       102
# 2 1.1  2    1       101       101
# 2 1.3  2    1       101       102
# 2 1.4  2    1       102       102
# 2 2    2    2       101       101
```